# Mockito tests pass except one verify

Tags: jdbc, mockito

I have all my tests pass, except this line in the first test:

```
verify(reimbursementDAO).getById(REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS.getId());
```

See the code below.

```java
package com.revature.services;

public class ReimbursementServiceTest
{

    private static ReimbursementService reimbursementService;
    private static ReimbursementDAO reimbursementDAO;

    private Reimbursement REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS;
    private Reimbursement GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_1;
    private Optional<Reimbursement>
      GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_2;

    private List<Reimbursement> GENERIC_ALL_PENDING_REIMBURSEMENTS;
    private User GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1;
    private User GENERIC_FINANCE_MANAGER_1;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception
    {
        reimbursementDAO = mock(ReimbursementDAO.class); // (IReimbursementDAO.class);
        reimbursementService = new ReimbursementService(reimbursementDAO);
        //reimbursementDAO = new ReimbursementDAO();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1 = new User(1, "genericEmployee1", "genericPassword", Role.EMPLOYEE);
        GENERIC_FINANCE_MANAGER_1 = new User(1, "genericManager1", "genericPassword", Role.FINANCE_MANAGER);

        REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS = new Reimbursement(2, Status.PENDING, GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1, null, 150.00);

        GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_1 = new Reimbursement(1, Status.PENDING, GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1, null, 100.00);
        GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_2 = Optional.ofNullable(new Reimbursement(2, Status.APPROVED, GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1,
            GENERIC_FINANCE_MANAGER_1, 150.00));

        GENERIC_ALL_PENDING_REIMBURSEMENTS = new ArrayList<Reimbursement>();
        GENERIC_ALL_PENDING_REIMBURSEMENTS.add(GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessPassesWhenUserIsFinanceManagerAndReimbursementExistsAndUpdateSuccessful()
    throws Exception
    {

        when(reimbursementDAO.getById(anyInt())).thenReturn(Optional.of(GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_1));
        when(reimbursementDAO.update(any())).thenReturn(GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_2);

        assertEquals(GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_2,
                     reimbursementService.process(REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS, Status.APPROVED,
                     GENERIC_FINANCE_MANAGER_1));

        //verify(reimbursementDAO).getById(REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS.getId());
        verify(reimbursementDAO).update(REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetReimbursementByStatusPassesWhenReimbursementsAreSuccessfullyReturned()
    {
        when(reimbursementDAO.getBystatus(any())).thenReturn(GENERIC_ALL_PENDING_REIMBURSEMENTS);

        assertEquals(GENERIC_ALL_PENDING_REIMBURSEMENTS,
                     reimbursementService.getReimbursementsByStatus(Status.PENDING));

        verify(reimbursementDAO).getBystatus(Status.PENDING);
    }
}
```

```java
public class ReimbursementDAO extends AbstractReimbursement
{
    public Optional<Reimbursement> getById(int id)
    {

        try(Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection())
        {
            String sql = "select * from ers_reimbursements where reimb_id=?;";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            Reimbursement reimb = null;
            UserService usrv = new UserService();
            //reimb_id, amount, submitted, resolved, description, author, receipt, resolver, status, reimb_type
            while(rs.next())
            {
                int reid = rs.getInt("reimb_id");
                double ramount = rs.getInt("reimb_amount");
                int res = rs.getInt("resolver");
                User resolver = null;

                String description = rs.getString("description");
                User rauthor = usrv.getUserById(rs.getInt("author")).get();
                if(res > 0)
                {
                    resolver = usrv.getUserById(res).get();
                }

                int rstatus = rs.getInt("reimb_status");
                Status r_status = Status.values()[--rstatus];
                int reimb_type = rs.getInt("reimb_type");
                ReimbType retype = ReimbType.values()[--reimb_type];

                User oth = rauthor;
                User re = resolver;
                reimb = new Reimbursement(reid, r_status, oth, re, ramount);
                return Optional.ofNullable(reimb);
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        };

        return Optional.empty();
    }


    public  List<Reimbursement> getBystatus(Status status)
    {

        try(Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection())
        {
            String sql = "select * from ers_reimbursements where reimb_status=?;";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql); //,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            int sta_id = status.ordinal() + 1;

            ps.setInt(1, sta_id);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            Reimbursement reimb = null;
            List<Reimbursement> reimbList = new ArrayList<Reimbursement>();
            IUserService usrv = new UserService();
            //reimb_id, amount, submitted, resolved, description, author, receipt, resolver, status, reimb_type
            while(rs.next())
            {
                //int id, Status status, User author, User resolver, double amount
                int reid = rs.getInt("reimb_id");
                double ramount = rs.getInt("reimb_amount");

                Optional<User> rauthor = usrv.getUserById(rs.getInt("author"));
                User oth = null;
                if(rauthor.isPresent())
                {
                    oth = rauthor.get();
                }

                int resol = rs.getInt("resolver");
                Optional<User> resolver = usrv.getUserById(resol);
                User re = null;

                if(resolver.isPresent())
                {
                    re = resolver.get();
                }
                else
                {
                    re = null;
                }
                int rstatus = rs.getInt("reimb_status");
                Status r_status = Status.values()[--rstatus]; //.PENDING;

                int reimb_type = rs.getInt("reimb_type");
                ReimbType retype = ReimbType.values()[--reimb_type]; //.TRAVEL;

                reimb = new Reimbursement(reid, r_status, oth, re, ramount);
                reimbList.add(reimb);
            }

            return reimbList;
        }
        catch(SQLException  e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
        return null;
    }


    public Optional<Reimbursement> update(Reimbursement unprocessedReimbursement)
    {
        try(Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection())
        {
            String sql = "update  ers_reimbursements set reimb_status=?," +
                         " resolver=?, resolved=?  where reimb_id=?;";

            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            int id = unprocessedReimbursement.getId();
            Status st = unprocessedReimbursement.getStatus();
            ps.setObject(1, st);

            ps.setInt(2, unprocessedReimbursement.getResolver().getId());
            ps.setObject(3, LocalDateTime.now());
            ps.setInt(4, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();

            try (ResultSet generatedKeys = ps.getGeneratedKeys())
            {
                if (generatedKeys.next())
                {
                    int reimid = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
                    Optional<Reimbursement> reim = getById(reimid);
                    System.out.println("Reimb " + reim.get() + " upLocalTimed!");
                    return reim;
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
            };

        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

```java
public class ReimbursementService
{
    private final ReimbursementDAO reimbDao;

    public ReimbursementService()
    {
        this(new ReimbursementDAO());
    }

    public ReimbursementService(ReimbursementDAO userDAO2)
    {
        this.reimbDao = userDAO2;
    }

    public Optional<Reimbursement> process(Reimbursement unprocessedReimbursement,
                                           Status finalStatus, User resolver)
                                           throws Exception
    {
        if (!resolver.getRole().equals(Role.FINANCE_MANAGER))
        {
            throw new RegistrationUnsuccessfulException("Resolver must be Finance Manager ");
        }
        // List<Reimbursement> l = DAO.getByStatus(Status.PENDING);

        if(unprocessedReimbursement.getId() == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception(" reimbursement not found");
        }

        if(unprocessedReimbursement.getStatus().equals(Status.PENDING))
        {
            unprocessedReimbursement.setResolver(resolver);
            unprocessedReimbursement.setStatus(finalStatus);
            Optional<Reimbursement> reimb = this.reimbDao.update(unprocessedReimbursement);
            if(reimb.isPresent())
            {
                return reimb;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("unsuccessful update");
            }
        }

        return Optional.ofNullable(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verification

```java
verify(reimbursementDAO).getById(REIMBURSEMENT_TO_PROCESS.getId());
```

fails because your service does not call the `getById()` method of your DAO.

It happens that your real DAO's `update()` method calls its own `getById()` method, but in your test you are using a mock DAO, where all functionality has been stubbed out. The `update()` method of the mock DAO does nothing more than return `GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_2` because that's what your test sets it up to do.

Comment: the test was written by trainer and I made some changes back and forth. I am suspecting the test is not set up correctly. How would I make that verify succeed? also please note I had  to edit DAO update line  ps.setObject(...) to ps.setInt(1,st.ordinal()+1)

Comment: @kobosh: try changing your DAO to return the ID of the reimbursement instead of looking up the reimbursement and returning it. Your service then calls your DAO's `getById()` method, with this ID, to get the `Reimbursement` object.

Comment: but look to first test : when(reimbursementDAO.update(any())).thenReturn(GENERIC_REIMBURSEMENT_2);

Comment: @kobosh:  you could always get the ID out of the returned reimbursement object and make a call to the DAO to look up the reimbursement again. However, that does seem a bit of a silly thing to do. If that test wasn't written by you then it doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: My question remains: why  test is not recognizing the call for getById in update method? I think it has to do with Optional ( Optional of null ? optional <reimbursement>?Optional.of?)

Comment: I removed optional from DAO methods but still get verify failing.

Comment: thanks Luke Wood. you were right. I added DAO getById to service and verify succeeded